# Как правильно указать logger в log4j2 в классе, который не является MainClass, чтобы log4j2 увидел appender

Tags: java, log4j2

Использую log4j2

**`log4j2.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration monitorInterval="3">
    <appenders>
        <File name="FILE" fileName="logs/error.log"/>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>

</configuration>
```

Есть Main Class: `Start`

Если пишу в `Start`

```
public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Start.class);
```

то всё нормально, логи пишутся
Если пишу подобные строки, например в `SomeClass`

```
public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

то log4j выдаёт во время выполнения

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (some.SomeClass).

и логи не пишутся для этого класса.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно пишете конфигурацию, попробуйте следующее, а потом добавите туда аппендер файла.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: тот же результат

Comment: Добавьте логгер для пакета в конфигурацию.

Comment: не совсем понял. <Loggers><Logger name="some.SomeClass">...</Logger>...</Loggers> - это имелось ввиду?

Comment: что-то на подобие, только для пакета.