# Log4j: как сконфигурировать файл?

Tags: java, log4j2

Я подключил к проекту Log4j2, дописал конфигурационный файл.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Файл я, чего уж греха таить, стащил откуда-то. Далее, я вызываю в коде лог следующим образом:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

...

final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AbstractEditor.class);

...

logger.info("updated: " + entity);
logger.debug("==> debug");
logger.info("==> info");
logger.warn("==> warn");
logger.error("==> error");
logger.fatal("==> fatal");
logger.trace("==> trace");
```

По идее, как я понял из конфигурационного файла, я должен получать в файл и консоль все логи уровнем DEBUG и выше. Но, по факту, с момента запуска приложения я получаю в консоль следующее:

```
15:08:52.285 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR ru.example.AbstractEditor - ==> error
15:08:52.292 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] FATAL ru.example.AbstractEditor - ==> fatal
```

Что-то мне подсказывает, что это вообще не из моего конфига, поскольку не совпадает паттерн сообщения. Сообщения в файл не пишутся. Приложение цепляет конфиг, поскольку когда я добавляю конфиг, из консоли пропадают вообще все логи, кроме двух строчек выше.

Помогите написать конфиг так, чтобы у меня в консоль и файл писались все логи начиная от DEBUG.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869188/204920

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис конфигурационного файла из первого `log4j`.

Вот здесь есть пример для `log4j2`  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties